# Bash to start missing debugger after update to 4.2

Tags: centos, bash, debug

I'm on Centos 7.2. Yesterday I've made an update of bash to version bash-4.2.46-19.el7.x86_64 and now on login I get this:

> -bash: /usr/share/bashdb/bashdb-main.inc: No such file or directory
>
> -bash: warning: cannot start debugger; debugging mode disabled

Of course I can install bashdb but I don't want to debug. Before I did the update this problem did not exist. It seems that debug is globally activated. I haven't configured debug (checked .bashrc and /etc/bashrc).

Haven't found a solution to get rid of this. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Check your profiles, and the scripts they call, for one or both of the lines:

```
  set -o functrace > /dev/null 2>&1
  shopt -s extdebug > /dev/null 2>&1
```

For instance, my version of this problem was instigated by iTerm2 in OSX, and its shell integration script. It all worked prior to the version of bash you mention, but now I get the two line error you sighted. It was a bear to sus out, because they were in a hidden file.

Comment: For the record, this issue is tracked by https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/4160